# How can I put UTF8 value to web.xml?

Tags: java, web.xml, java-ee-8

I'm thinking to put some UTF-8 words into `web.xml` as `env-entry-value`, but somehow that will cause my war become not deployable to my server. A case of my setting that causes deployment failure look like below.

```
<env-entry>
    <description>Msg text</description>
    <env-entry-name>Msg_Text</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>兔子</env-entry-value>
  </env-entry>
```

error msgs

```
10:56:41,498 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Test.war (runtime-name: Test.war) in 69ms
10:56:41,920 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015858: Undeployed "Test.war" (runtime-name: "Test.war")
10:56:41,920 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."Test.war".PARSE
```

Can anyone teach me how to do it?

======Update======

Tried that with semi-colon again, `&#53F0;`, then it got other error

```
    23:57:43,222 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014612: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Test.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Test.war\".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"Test.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018014: Failed to parse XML descriptor \"/C:/Windows/System32/content/Test.war/WEB-INF/web.xml\" at [58,24]
    Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'F' (code 70); expected a decimal number.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [58,24]"}}
23:57:44,144 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Test.war (runtime-name: Test.war) in 915ms
23:57:44,144 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."Test.war".PARSE
```

If I fill it with normal ascii characters, it works good. Do I missed anything else on that?

Comment: This is most likely an encoding problem which cannot be analyzed without additional information if you cannot open the xml file in a modern browser  . I would suggest using the “&#hex;” notation (where hex is the Unicode value for that character, repeat for each)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen tried it with `&#53F0`, and jboss is still not happy about it. =/

Comment: You need the semi-colon as well.

Comment: The obvious question is: Have you have got <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> as the first line in your web.xml file?

Comment: @Jonathan Yeah, it does. Ain't it suppose to be part of default value when you create a web project using modern IDE lke eclipse or intellij? eclipse seems like it will do it at least

Comment: @Jonathan That is the default if nothing is stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. web.xml must contain `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` or `<?xml version="1.0"?>`: any other encoding would corrupt Unicode text content.
2. Edit web.xml in UTF-8; a programmer's editor like NotePad++ would do.
3. For hexadecimal do not forget the `x`: **`&#x53F0;`**.

Comment: OMG! that little `x` is the last puzzle! thanks!

Comment: But it doesn't explain why your UTF-8 char wasn't accepted by JBoss ...

Comment: @Jonathan is right, hence my first two points on encoding. A pity that part is left unsolved.

Comment: My bad, I forgot the x.